# Как собрать vue-проект в docker-compoce

Tags: node.js, vue.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Структура проекта:

```
-- project
----> configs // Конфиги сборки докера
------> application
-------- Dockerfile
-------- php-fpm.conf
------> nginx
-------- Dockerfile
-------- php-fpm.conf
------> nodejs
-------- Dockerfile
-- databases // Базы дынных
-- production // Код проетка (PHP + VUE)
-- .env
-- .env.example
-- docker-compose.yml
-- README.md
```

`dockerfile` сервиса `nodejs`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as front

WORKDIR /var/www/project/production/frontend

VOLUME ["/var/www/project/production/frontend"]

RUN apk add --no-cache bash

RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

Сервис:

```
  # NODEJS - Service
  nodejs:
    build: configs/nodejs
    container_name: nodejs_container
    depends_on:
      - application
```

Почему при выполнении `docker-compose build` в контейнер не примонтировалась директория `/var/www/project/production/frontend`(вывод команды `ls -la`)?

Соответственно не собирается проект из-за отстутствия файла `package.json`.

Comment: а вы указали что должно примонтироваться в вашу папку в контейнере (комманда volume создает том, но она не делает bind к папке на хосте)? по информации из вопроса, выглядит так, что вы создали volume и все, он пустой

Comment: @ExplodingKitten я предполагал, что VOLUME монтирует(прокидывает ссылку) директироию. Как мне забиндить директорию, т. е. мне необходимо чтобы контейнер  выполнил скрипт(сборку) и остановился?

Comment: Как ни странно, вам надо именно забиндить папку, а не создавать volume. Но лучше место этого получать код из VCS.

Comment: @user7860670 Я разобрался в вопросе. `volume` и  `--volume` или `-v` не одно и тоже. Если `volume` написать в `dockerfile`, то просто будет создана директория в контейнере(том), а если при запуске контейнера то будет примантирована(bind) директория с хоста(локальной машины). Я просто пока не готов дать ответ. Всё проверяю и тестирую)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Чтобы **Docker** примонтировал(**binding**) дирикторию необходимо при запуске контейнера передать путь к директории на хосте(локальная машина), которую будем монтировать и путь где будет эта директория в контейнере. Пример:  -v `/var/www/my-site:/var/www/my-site` или --volume `/var/www/my-site:/var/www/my-site`;
- Дополняем image `node:lts-alpine`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
```

- Описываем сервис в `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
# NODEJS - Service
  nodejs:
    build: configs/nodejs
    container_name: nodejs_container
    volumes:
      - /var/www/my-site:/var/www/my-site
    working_dir: /var/www/my-site
    command: sh init.sh
```

- Когда поднимим контаинер выполнится скрипт:

```bsh
npm install
npm run build
```